# How do I get rid of the Chrome extension TopSearchEngine?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, malware-removal

Somehow (probably me when I wasn't paying attention), a plugin was installed in Chrome called TopSearchEngine. I remove the plugin from Chrome every few weeks but occasionally (every few weeks) Chrome crashes and the plugin is reinstalled when I restart Chrome. I don't know what information to provide to be helpful in answering the question since I remove the plugin from Chrome all the time and I have no idea how it comes back. The ID is cejilmjikdbpfgjmbakcdbehnmjagdjn (if that matters). Under details is listed Inspect views, background page. It always allows itself On all sites and in Incognito and the source isn't from the Chrome Web Store. I would like to remove it permanently. Any thoughts on how I could report this thing or how I can accomplish removing it so it never comes back?

Comment: Have you done a hard/factory reset of Chrome? chrome://settings/reset

Comment: Nope, I didn't even know about that. But I already disabled the extension by hand since I didn't know what it was doing if I left it on (and I need to work). I'll try this when the extension reinstalls itself.

Comment: @spikey_richie I tried resetting things and it didn't work.